# Preserve link breaks with marked.js

Tags: javascript, markdown

Markdown is great but it has some pretty funky rules around line breaks. I want to preserve line breaks from the original text in the rendered html but I'm having a hell of a time working out how to do this. In the following example there are two empty lines between five and six but the markdown renderer used by stackoverflow only shows one blank line in the output.

- one
- two
- three

four

five

six

I'm open to anything at this point, any javascript markdown engine, any hacks, just something that will get this working...

Comment: Would someone care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Paragraphs in Markdown are [separated by "one or more blank lines"](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p), so the behaviour that you are seeing should be expected:

> ### Paragraphs and Line Breaks
>
> A paragraph is simply one or more consecutive lines of text, separated by one or more blank lines. (A blank line is any line that looks like a blank line — a line containing nothing but spaces or tabs is considered blank.) Normal paragraphs should not be indented with spaces or tabs.

For the record, I don't think this is "funky" at all. Markdown was designed to target HTML, which collapses consecutive whitespace.

`<br>` tags may be generated by ending a line with two or more spaces:

> When you *do* want to insert a `<br />` break tag using Markdown, you end a line with two or more spaces, then type return.

But note that a line that is *just* two spaces will not work, as that "looks like a blank line" and is thus treated as a paragraph break.

On at least some implementations, Unicode [`NO-BREAK SPACE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)s can be used with two or more regular trailing spaces to create extra "blank" lines, e.g. using underscores to represent non-breaking spaces and periods to represent regular spaces:

```
one..
_..
_..
two
```

renders on Stack Overflow as

```
<p>one <br>
&nbsp; <br>
&nbsp; <br>
two</p>
```

Comment: that's a good point about html collapsing white space. Markdown gets used in a lot of places where you want to give users some formatting but not full access to html properties (colors, fonts etc.). In these cases users find it confusing that multiple blank lines are collapsed.

Comment: I guess I just need to find an implementation where I can control this breaking behaviour (I'm looking for a js implementation if anyone has any suggestions).